# Doctrine ORM with Symfony2 - Sorting a ManyToMany relationship

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, symfony

I have 2 entities.

```
Mag
Page
```

Which have a ManyToMany relationship. A Page can have many Mags attached to it, but I need to  allow the user to adjust the sort order of the Mags.

At the moment ,the order is just based on the `id` of the Mag in the `Page_Mag` table

So I need a sort field, but then I would need a sort field for each Page->Mag relationship, as there are many Pages which can have any number of Mags attached.

I'm struggling to get my head around the best way of doing this without making a massive mess of my schema!

Any ideas?

My annotations are:

```
  /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Page", mappedBy="magazines" , cascade = {"persist", "remove"})
    */
    protected $Page;
```

and

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Magazine", inversedBy="id" , cascade = {"persist", "remove"})
*/
protected $magazines;
```

EDIT:
To try and explain better , this is what the relationship could be like, where the order of the mags is important to be maintained :

```
Page_id 1  -> Mag_id:4
           -> Mag_id:2
           -> Mag_id:1

Page_id 2  -> Mag_id:12
           -> Mag_id:1
           -> Mag_id:4
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this isn't really a direct answer, this is how I solved my problem. Custom Twig Extension to perform the sort in the view.

```
public static function magorder($magazines , $order)
{
   $newMagazines = array();
   $order = explode(',', $order);

   foreach ($magazines as $magazine)
   {
        $newMagazines[array_search($magazine->getId(), $order)] = $magazine;
   }

   return $newMagazines;
}
```

this is then called within a `for`:

```
{{ page.magazines|magorder(page.magorder) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you would want to sort your Mags but you most likely need a [MagRepository Class](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes) that uses DQL (or SQL if you like) to fetch the entities you want in the order you want. And then use that repository in your controller.

EDIT:

I think I got your question wrong the first time.

Unfortunately, getting a field in your join table that specifies the position of a Page within a Mag cannot be done using annotations alone. You need a join-entity for that that has one-to-many associations to your Page and Mag entities.

Comment: thanks. That makes sense, but I need to know how to add in sort field to the ManyToMany I think? So my order could be Mag_id=1 , Mag_id=4 , Mag_id=2 etc. EDIT: just saw your EDIT! :)

Comment: Do you just want to sort the mags oder the pages inside a mag or both? If its the mags, then only the mags need a sort field. If its the pages inside a mag, go with the join-entity.

Comment: Confusingly , by Pages , I'm not talking about 'Magazine' pages, I'm talking about 'Web' Pages. So Page is the main entity, which has many 'Magazines' , but each 'Magazine' can be on many 'Pages\ :)

Comment: ok, but you could still solve that with a sort field on you join-table/entity since the sorting is probably only one way. if not, add two sort fields. one for page -> mag and one for mag -> page.

Comment: I gave up trying to get the entities to deal with my sorting and implemented a custom Twig Extension to perform the sort for me instead. Thanks for your help though.